# Setting height for UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to change the height of a UICollectionViewCell depending on the size of the content in the cell (specifically a UILabel). I set the UILabel height in

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewcellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I then set the UICollectionViewCell height in

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

It appears the second method is called before the first one, so the height of the label has not been calculated yet. Complete code found below (warning: needs a tidy!). Any ideas?

```
    -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView
                                    dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                    forIndexPath:indexPath];


    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,10,width - 90,0)];
    label.text = @"Hellfoneofinerigoneriognwirotngwtngowirnthointgonowenfkqejb fgjkreb glknrlegkn ewlj qerlgjnweofjpeorihgpireghiperhgorgrngl;rtnh;ltm;l";
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:17];
    [label sizeToFit];

    [myCell.contentView addSubview:label];
    CGSize labelY = [label bounds].size;
    i = labelY.height;
    NSLog(@"Height: %d", i);


        return myCell;
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegate>
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 NSLog(@"Height: %d", i);

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if(result.height == 568)
        {
           return CGSizeMake(300.f, i);

        }
        if(result.height == 667)
        {
          return CGSizeMake(340.f, i);

        }
        if(result.height == 736)
        {
          return CGSizeMake(370.f, i);


        }
    }
    return CGSizeMake(300.f, i);

}
```

EDIT: Didn't really explain the error. The height of i is equal to zero when  `-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath .` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked by creating a Label in the height method and determining the height there.

Answer (score 0):

The layout delegate method `- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` will
execute first before datasource method `-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, and `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` calculated size of all the cell, then start to build them.

So, you should just fetch the content by indexPath , then calculate height for displaying, apply the height value in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to implement is Self Sizing `UICollectionViewCell`s.  To implement that you need to:

- set the `estimatedItemSize` for the flowLayout
- pin the labels to the top, bottom, leading, and trailing edges
- make sure the `Vertical Content Hugging Priority` for the last label is 250
- and implement `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting` in your UICollectionViewCell

I've written a longer blog post about Self Sizing `UICollectinViewCell`s here:
http://parveenkaler.com/posts/self-sizing-uicollectionviewcell-swift